# SMS Filtering Application

Tags: android, filter, sms, block

I am working on SMS Filtering application. The thing i need to do is that every incoming SMS must go through my SMS Filtering application and then if the user mark it as NOT SPAM then it goes to the Default Messaging Application.

Basic Flow that i needed is that:
1- Incoming Sms received firstly on my app, if user mark it as not Spam it goes to inbox of user default Sms application and sms ringtone called
2- If user mark it as Spam then no vibration or any other notification happened and it does not go to inbox of user default application.

Is this possible that every sms first received on my app and then go to default app of user defined? Help Please

Comment: in fact for sms you got a default application that handle all SMS Intent, so in your case i think you got to do a complete SMS app.